# Peak memory usage does not go beyond a limit

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, jvm

I see that with -Xmx2g, the peak memory reaches 1G and does major collections (marksweep collector). With -Xmx3g, it reaches 1.5G and does a major collections. With -Xmg4g, it reaches 2G and does major collections. But, from here I tried increasing max memory to 6G, 8G, 12G and all the times the peak memory reaches 2G does major collections.

How to make it use beyond 2G? I didn't come across any setting for this. Does -Xms matter here? Fo those -Xmx, I made -Xms half of -Xmx.

I am using Jetty, Java 1.6.024.

UPDATE: 
Yes, I am using 64-bit JVM. 
The JVM options I am using are: -Xmx6g -Xms3g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
The way I am determining the peak memory is by looking at the memory graph in JConsole. It reaches 2G and drops (major collection). Old Gen reaches 1.5G max and then drop happens.

Thanks,
Prams.

Comment: Is it a fair assumption that you're using a 64-bit JVM?  It's worth asking, because the 32-bit JVM has a 2GB size limit built in.

Comment: I think it's safe to say it's a 64-bit JVM, because Java will terminate without running the program at all if you specify a heap size much larger than 1500m (the exact limit is JVM-dependent).

Comment: Did you try to play around with -XX properties?

Comment: How are you determining "peak memory"?  Is that from ps or via JMX?

Comment: Hi, it would help of you gave us the full command line to see exactly which options you are setting. 

Without the command line it is impossible to determine why you are seeing the behavior you are seeing.

The concurrent mark sweep collection is designed to minimize pauses when collection so it is possible that allowing the heap to grow much bigger runs contrary to that goal.  By default it has a maximum pause time as well as limits on the size of each generation and GC boundary.

Most of this behavior can be tweaked to meet your needs but many factors go into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three memory regions, eden, survivor and tenured space.

What I suspect is happenings is that either the tenured or eden spaces are not growing as you increase the maximum size.

The reason these two regions matters is that when the tenured space fills a Full GC is triggered (I suspect this size is growing)  When the eden space fills and there is not enough space in the survivor space to copy all the objects left, a full GC is also triggered.

If this is the cause of your problem, you are creating a very large number of medium lived objects which is likely to be a performance problem, unless you can reduce the number created.
An alternative is to specifiy a larger new size which increases the eden size.

Try `-mx12g -XX:NewSize=10g - verbosegc`

The last option will give your the sizes of the individual spaces when they are cleaned up.

Comment: Peter, thanks for the answer.

I have a follow up question. One of our object's retained size is about 4MB. And we create one such object per minute and replace it with an earlier minute's object in a static ConcurrentHashMap. As far I can see this is the biggest object. Of course there are lot of other String objects and other temporary objects, but they are all much smaller than 4MB. Is this too big a size for an Eden space of 3G? Because when I had 6G, I tried with NewRatio of 1 and that didn't help the peak usage to go beyond 2G.

Thanks.

Comment: Large objects are allocated to the tenured space directly. If you have an object which is actually made of lots of little objects which then they should be allocated to the eden space.  For large objects like this, you are better off recycling them yourself if you can in a simple manner.

Comment: Setting NewSize to large size helped in reaching higher peak memory objects. Thanks.

I will let you know my configuration and some details of the objects that we create. And will ask one question (in the next comment).
The profiler indicates 2 places consuming lot of memory: 
1) About 5 strings (each 110KB) per second are created. 
2) An object containing 4 objects (of a single class) is created one per minute and replaced into a static concurrenthashmap (so map contains only 1 object at any time). Each of those 4 objects contain 10K arraylists, 10K Date and other strings, etc.

Comment: continued from my previous comment..

-Xmx6g -Xms3g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

In #1, replace operation is executed for each string we create.

In #2, the retained size of the parent object is 3.5MB, but does not contain anything other than those 4 objects which again contains 10K of other collections and objects.

The behavior is that the memory usage keeps increasing and at one point major collection (2GB) happens. minor collection (700MB) also happen about once a minute.

Question: Do you think #1 is actually causing the eden space to be full and so is pushing objects in #2 to tenure space? Thx.

Comment: That is possible. What do you see when you try the options I suggested
?

Comment: -Xmx12g -Xms3g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:NewSize=8g

With these options, I see that lot more objects are getting collected by GC by the minor collections (clearly because Eden space is lot larger now).

Comment: The minimum size doesn't matter when the new size is larger. ;)